# Why is the same query syntax not supported in Log Analytics and Application Insight Logs?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am trying to figure out why the same query is not valid in both a Log Analytics and Application Insights workspace.

I've been working on creating a [cross-resource query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query) and when I write the syntax in Log Analytics it has a syntax error around the workspace operator.  It is successful when I do the same thing in an Application Insights query.

The query looks like this:

```sql
union 
workspace("DefaultWorkspace-b432aa91-rrrr-qqqq-zzzz-aabbba7e8f42-WUS2").SecurityEvent
,workspace("DefaultWorkspace-fca02198a-aaaa-eeee-cccc-aaad9fbf7302-EUS").SecurityEvent 
| count
```

Since in both workspaces it references other workspaces, I would think it would be portable if queried under the same tenant (which I am).  In Azure Log Analytics it gives me the error:

```sql
Unknown function: 'workspace'.
```

I am running these in the Azure portal at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a space after the comma? This query is working for my own workspaces.

union 
workspace("DefaultWorkspace-b432aa91-rrrr-qqqq-zzzz-aabbba7e8f42-WUS2").SecurityEvent
, **workspace**("DefaultWorkspace-fca02198a-aaaa-eeee-cccc-aaad9fbf7302-EUS").SecurityEvent 
| count

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but suggestions.

As far as I know, only if the query missing table name, then it will cause the error **"Unknown function: 'workspace'."**. Like below:

[image]

So first, make sure in your query, you are adding table name after `workspace("xxx")`. I notice that in your query, you're using the correct syntax, but just want to make sure the table name is there.

Second, if you're adding table name after `workspace("xxx")`, and still get this error. You can try just use the query below to check if the `workspace("xxx")` works:

```
workspace("adsmit-test").Heartbeat
| count
```

Please feel free to let me know if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same statement 2 weeks later in both an Application Insights and Log Analytics and it works in both.